# forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred

Tags: linux, fortran

I really need your help!!! I am wondering if it is because of the array coor.

I compiled a fortran program using ifort msd.f90 -o msd.x

After I ran ./msd.x it gave me segmentation fault

My Fortrain code is:

```
program mean_square_displacement
  implicit none
  integer i,j,k,natom,mstep
  integer, parameter :: mmax=5000,nmax=1000,kmax=3 
  real*16 vector(3,3),d(3)
  real*16,dimension(kmax,nmax,mmax) :: coor
  real*16 msdtotal(mmax),msd(nmax,mmax)


  open(unit=8,file="vector")
  read(unit=8,fmt=*) (vector(k,1),k=1,3)
  read(unit=8,fmt=*) (vector(k,2),k=1,3)
  read(unit=8,fmt=*) (vector(k,3),k=1,3)


  do j=0,mmax
  do i=0,nmax
  do k=0,kmax
  coor(k,i,j)=0.d0  
  enddo
  enddo
  enddo



 open(unit=9,file="trace")

  i=0
  j=0
  10    continue
  read(unit=9,fmt=*,end=100) (d(k),k=1,3)
  i=i+1

     coor(1,i,j)=d(1)
     coor(2,i,j)=d(2)
     coor(3,i,j)=d(3)

    write(6,20), coor(1,i,j),coor(2,i,j),coor(3,i,j)

  goto 10
  100   continue

  natom=130
  mstep=j


  20    format(3(1x,f12.9))

  stop
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Segmentation faults are often caused by accessing arrays out of their allocated boundaries.

In your case, the array `coor` is allocated as `coor(1:kmax,1:nmax,1:nmax)` with `1` being the default lower bound. However, you regularly access the array with one or more indices being `0`.

If you want to change the lower bound, you can allocate your array using `dimension(0:kmax,0:nmax,0:nmax)`.

---

Btw: Your read loop doesn't increment `j` and you should avoid using `goto` as it is bad style and hard to read.

The end of a file can be detected with the `IOSTAT=` specifier. Your read loop would the look like:

```
i=0
j=0
do
    read(unit=9,fmt=*,iostat=ios) (d(k),k=1,3)
    if (iostat /= 0) exit ! exit the read loop if reading breaks (e.g. EOF)

    i=i+1
    j=j+1 -- this might be missing from your original source?!

    coor(1,i,j)=d(1)
    coor(2,i,j)=d(2)
    coor(3,i,j)=d(3)

    write(6,20), coor(1,i,j),coor(2,i,j),coor(3,i,j)
end do
```

According to the documentation of [gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IS_005fIOSTAT_005fEND.html#IS_005fIOSTAT_005fEND) and [ifort](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/526375) there is a function called `IS_IOSTAT_END` in the Fortran 2003 standard. Unfortunately, I can't find the location of its specification. However, according to [the gfortran documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IS_005fIOSTAT_005fEND.html#IS_005fIOSTAT_005fEND) "the function is equivalent to comparing the variable with the `IOSTAT_END` parameter of the intrinsic module `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV`", which is standardized, indeed.